# Reinterpretation of struct-emulator without interfaces/boxing in a Managed Environment

Tags: c#, .net, types, interface, casting

**I have a class that's meant to emulate a (non-derivable) struct and add functionality (events)**
It has exact same public interface, but some custom internal code for the event of a mutation.
I need to pass said class into a function that expects the struct my class emulates, but I need to avoid boxing/unboxing since it is so slow.

**How do I get said function to accept my class if the emulated struct isn't under my control, and doesn't derive from an interface?**  My class has the exact same public functions/members/syntax.

---

**Concrete Example:**

**The XNA `GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives` function asks for an array of `IVertexType`'s.**
It seems like such a waste sometimes to have to have to call List.ToArray(), thus making an entire copy, just because a function specifically wants a System.Array type input. A List has the same syntax and functionality as an Array. If the function were to accept the input class there wound't be any problems.

Comment: here, have some magic fairy dust. Sprinkling that over your code is about the only way to achieve what you want. :)

Comment: `List` and `Array` have different (but similar) syntax and functionality. The internal usage of the array within `DrawUserPrimitives` could be taking advantage of block copies, fixed array length, etc. Perhaps you should alter your own design if you want to avoid a `List.ToArray` call.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair well the function only takes an array, so I'd have to store the vertices as an array. I stored it as a list because the data is volatile, so what can I do?

Comment: @Griffin Then roll your own `List` implementation that provides direct access to the underlying array. I don't know how `DrawUserPrimitives` will behave though if you have empty elements in the array. How many vertices are you pushing here? Are you sure this is where your bottleneck in your system is?

Comment: @ChrisSinclair I'm reluctant to create my own List since all the functions will probably end up even slower when written by me (due to my lack of skill) =p. How hard do you think it'd be to learn/copy how such standard classes work internally?

Comment: @Griffin I'd make doubly sure that this is your performance bottleneck. I doubt you're going to get much out of rolling your own or that avoiding the creation of the array is going to be your silver bullet.

Answer (score 1):

Why cant you implement IVertexType and use an array IVertexType[]?  If there is a struct that implements this, then you can compose your implementation by wrapping the struct and returning the structs values.

Comment: I'm trying to change the behavior of myType[], not the behavior of the individual vertices. I tried wrapping them in a class that derived from array, but the function just won't take it.